# Load language files inside custom library

Tags: custom-component, language, libraries

I have a a library inside `\libraries\mylib\`.

That library contains an `include.php` which uses following to load language files that are also inside a `/language` folder in the library:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
// load english language file if some constants are not translated
$lang->load('mylib', JPATH_SITE . '/libraries/mylib', 'en-GB', true);
// load active language file
$lang->load('mylib', JPATH_SITE . '/libraries/mylib', null, true);
```

My site uses the two languages German and English. The folders inside the library look like this:

```
\libraries\mylib\language\de-DE\de-DE.mylib.ini
\libraries\mylib\language\en-GB\en-GB.mylib.ini
```

Now to the problem.

German is setup as the the standard language inside Joomla. So if I run the site in german, the language files in the library get loaded correctly, as shown by the language debugger:

```
**Loaded** : JROOT/libraries/mylib/language/en-GB/en-GB.mylib.ini
**Loaded** : JROOT/libraries/mylib/language/de-DE/de-DE.mylib.ini
```

If i switch the language to english the library languages don't get loaded anymore:

```
Not loaded : JROOT/language/en-GB/en-GB.mylib.ini
```

Looks like in english the whole library folder path gets lost...?

I checked everything like filenames, parsing errors, folders ans so on. No idea whats going on.

Maybe someone has an idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Extension-specific language folder is an old and not recommended way of handling language files. Joomla! is moving towards the use of only global language folders. Whether or not your code should still work I can't tell, you might want to ask this on the [Issue Tracker](https://issues.joomla.org/).

Until you receive a response there you can workaround the issue by loading your files later during `onAfterRoute` event or by moving to use the global language folders as well.

Comment: Well I have two extensions, that use their own language files but also a single language file from the library. Like described it works when on the default language, but not when switching the language.

Comment: Also not using extension-specific language folders.

Comment: By extension-specific I mean your language files are placed in your extension's directory and not in global (`language` or `administrator/language`) directory.

Comment: Yes, that is not the case. Language files are placed in global folders and are getting loaded without problems. It's only about the language files in the library folder.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Language Filter plugin does not load language files from extension folders.

Comment: Like said I have no extension language folders.

Comment: Library is an extension. The issue is with files placed in `libraries/mylib/language` directory. Move them to global language directories to solve the issue.

Comment: Well, i can't move them there because they get used by two extension. I changed now the language file generation process, so the extension files and the library files get merged during generation.