# Using Language Constant File in a Module

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, multilingual

I'm creating a module but I need it to be multilingual. I know that I can create field params, duplicate the module, and set different values for these params based on the languague but I would like to know if there's any way to use Language Constant like we do with components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you set them up in a similar way to components.

In your module directory create a folder `language`, and then a subfolder for the language within that, and into that subfolder put your language INI file(s). If your module is called `mod_example` then:

Inside `language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_example.ini` put

```
MOD_EXAMPLE_ONE="one"
```

Inside `language/es-ES/es-ES.mod_example.ini` put

```
MOD_EXAMPLE_ONE="uno"
```

Inside your module xml file include the language folder within a `<languages>` section (updated from within a `<files>` section based on the comment from Sharky below):

```
<languages folder="language">
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_example.ini</language>
    <language tag="es-ES">es-ES/es-ES.mod_example.ini</language>
</languages>
```

Then in your module you can use language strings in the usual way:

```
echo JText::_("MOD_EXAMPLE_ONE");
```

Comment: Thank you very much because I was actually doing some sort of work around without knowing I could use this.

Comment: Installing language files to extension directory (using `<files>` tag) is the old and not recommended way. It breaks on multilingual sites. Language files should be installed to global language directory using `<languages>` tag.

Comment: @Sharky thanks for the advice - I've updated the answer accordingly. Is there a Joomla document which I can reference which says that the old way is deprecated? I tried it on my own multilingual site and it worked ok.

Comment: Sorry, I might have misled you. This works fine with modules. Looks like the issue is specific to libraries (https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/26486/12652). Though I would still recommend using the global language folder since that's the first place Joomla! looks in.

Comment: Thank you both of you. The first solution Robbie prposed is working nicely anyway. Thank you once again.